# How to parse files in Android from a public directory on the server

Tags: java, android, html-parsing, directory-structure

I'm trying to parse files from a public directory like this:

[image]

And the condition has to be parsed from Android (Java). Have you ever done a workaround?

My main solution is parsing html to check the files listed in the directory, but I'm looking for a better and more efficient way to do it.

I'm not trying to parse from FTP, but from any public directory.

Thank you in advance.
Rafael.

Answer (score 0):

If this is FTP directory, you can use Apache Commons FTPClient

[example](http://wiki-android.blogspot.ru/2012/12/creating-android-ftp-client-ftp.html)

Comment: Good point, thank you very much, but I'm looking for any public directory not only from FTP. Thanks anyway.

Comment: If it is HTML and website doesn't provide API, the only way is to parse HTML :)